# Getting parent id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="item">
      <li id="user_one">Username
          <ul>
            <li class="click">Click Here</li>
        </ul>
```

Basically I want to be able to get the ID of the parent LI.  This is what I currently have:

```
$(this).parents("ul").find(".item li").attr("id");
```

This works sort of, there are many of these lists on a single page, all with different ID's.  It always returns the first item, instead of really the parent from what was clicked.

Any help would be awesome... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().closest('li').attr('id')
```

I chose this way over parents because:

> [[.parents] Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Which to me means it will get all the elements before it is filtered, but closest will return the first element it finds.